# Increasing bounty already made by you

Tags: discussion, bounty

What about idea of allowing to increase bounty made by you previously?
Is it good or not? If not then for what kind of reasons (how easy to implement - counts too)?

My motivation - I made bounty (100) when I first time reached enough reputation (something more 100). It was two days ago. Now I have again more than 100 reputation points and, naturally for me, there appears idea to increase this bounty.

Comment: But why?  If the question got no answer when first posted in December, and gets no answer in February with bounty of 100, it seems a waste to try again with bounty of 1000 or something, since the result will most likely be no answer again.

Comment: @GEdgar People are strange. Also 100 is small amount and maybe I value answer to question more than that. Or I believe that 100 will not attract best minds. Or anything else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll be able to set another bounty after the present one expires or is awarded, subject to the restriction $$\text{new bounty}\ge \min(\,2\cdot\text{previous bounty}, 500\,)$$ At present it is [not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67918/) to change the amount of the bounty after it was set. And I don't see a convincing reason to add such as feature. 
It's one more link to include in the interface, one more dialog window to design, and more code to maintain.

Also consider the added ambiguity concerning whether or not the increased amount means the bounty period is renewed, and ensuing questions on meta sites. No matter which way it is, and no matter how clearly the rules are stated, some users will expect things to work their way, and will launch a debate arguing their case. Witness the unending meta.SO questions about why fruitless bounties are not returned, and arguments over whether they should be.