# Is it possible to increase the amount of a bounty after it has been awarded?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have started a bounty on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450607/on-siegel-mass-formula) about few minutes ago.

Considering [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27037/is-there-any-force-to-award-the-bounty) and not to *wasting* my reputation(s);
so I have decided to devote the least possible amount 
(of worth $+50$ reputation) for this bounty.

---

Consider the following situation:
Someone answers my question and his/her answer **satisfies** me very well;
Is there any way to **award more reputation** on that answer?

---

For the sake of comfortability 
let's consider there are different answers 
**A**, $B, C, \cdot \cdot \cdot$ on my question; 
and only **A** satisfies me;

then my question is:

- Is it possible to increase the amount of a bounty, 
  to award more on the answer **A**?
- Is it possible to award that bounty on the answer **A**; 
  and again starting another bounty on it, 
  and award it again on **A**?
  [Is it possible to award two bounties on the same answer?]
- Is there any way to show my gratitude for well-satisfying answers?

Comment: I think the answer to [this older question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8463/11619) is still valid. IOW, you cannot increase the bounty while this bounty is active (nor at the time of awarding it, me thinks), but you can start another afterwards. Also, it is perfectly ok to start a bounty for the sole purpose of rewarding an existing answer. In the interest of fairness you should then pick that bounty reason so that nobody else is fooled.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen♦ ; my dear Jyrki Lahtonen♦, why to be fooled? Can you explain more?

Comment: If you start a bounty for the purposes of rewarding an existing answer, you should say so. Otherwise somebody may think the bounty is still for anyone to grab. One of the listed bounty reasons is *One of the existing answers is exemplary....* So you should use that, if that is your intention. You can still add a comment telling that if an even better answer comes up, you consider awarding that instead. As long as you are open about it that is IMO ok.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen♦ ; Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Note that while the first bounty can be as little as $50$ points, additional bounties you put on [the same Question will be higher amounts](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).